# Magento 2.3.2 custom Cron status is always missed or pending

Tags: magento-cron

Magento 2.3.2 custom Cron job won't run. Status is always missed or pending and next time it is not working

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
<group id="default">
    <job name="pending_ordersftp" instance="Epok\OrderManagementFtp\Cron\PendingOrders" method="execute">
        <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
</config>
```

Comment: it would be better if you add your cron code. xml files and php file

Comment: can you tell where you created this xml file ?and can you replace your method name with other method name instead using "execute" ?and can you give here code for method as well ?